# Long form of ancestor & descendant - Xpath axes

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm aware of the functionality of these Xpath axes but I want to know what is the long form of these axes in Xpath. It will be very helpful in understanding the backend of these axes.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by the "long form" of an axis, and what do you mean by the "backend" of an axis?

Comment: I believe OP wants to know more about the formal axis names behind the abbreviated forms such as `..` for `parent::` and `//` for `descendant-or-self`.  I've provided guidance to the XPath 1.0 Recommendation [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52203921/290085) to try to help.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the long form of all XPath axis is given by the [`AxisName`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-AxisName) production in the [*W3C XPath 1.0 Recommendation*](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/):

> ```
> [6] AxisName      ::= 'ancestor'  
>                     | 'ancestor-or-self'  
>                     | 'attribute' 
>                     | 'child' 
>                     | 'descendant'    
>                     | 'descendant-or-self'    
>                     | 'following' 
>                     | 'following-sibling' 
>                     | 'namespace' 
>                     | 'parent'    
>                     | 'preceding' 
>                     | 'preceding-sibling' 
>                     | 'self'
> ```

The syntax of the context of `AxisName` is given by the [`AxisSpecifier`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-AxisSpecifier) production:

> ```
> [5] AxisSpecifier ::= AxisName '::' | AbbreviatedAxisSpecifier
> ```

**See also**

- The **semantics** of each axis are described in [Section 2.2 Axes](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#axes).
- The axis **abbreviations** are described in [Section 2.5 Abbreviated
  Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#path-abbrev).